# My GameObject always stays inactive, SetActive(true) doesn't work and the coroutine won't start

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a number of Prefabs stored in an array and instantiate one at a time by clicking a button. The object appears but is always inactive.

I've searched for hours for an answer and tried a lot but the problem stays the same. I hope it's ok to ask, even though there are several similar questions but none of the answers solves my problem.
Like I've already described, I want to instantiate a GameObject from an array per button click and the object indeed appears but when I try to start a coroutine on it(if that's helpful, it's an IEnumerator that shall let the Object fade out by handling it's colours alpha channel), I always get an error that says the GameObject is inactive. I'm not able to set it active by writing myPrefab.gameObject.SetActive(true) and I've tried to call it at several places in my code. It always stays inactive. Has anybody any idea what might be the problem?

```
public class Class1 : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private MyClass[] myPrefabs;

    private MyClass myCurrentPrefab;

    private int myIndex;

    public void ButtonEffect()
    {
        InstantiatePrefab();
        myCurrentPrefab.OnButtonEffect();
    }

    private void InstantiatePrefab()
    {
        myIndex = Random.Range(0, myPrefabs.Length);
        myCurrentPrefab = myPrefabs[myIndex];
        Instantiate(myCurrentPrefab);
    }
}

public class MyClass : MonoBehaviour
{
    private SpriteRenderer mySprite;

    private void Start()
    {
        mySprite = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
    }

    private void Awake()
    {
        this.gameObject.SetActive(true)
    } 

    private void OnButtonEffect()
    {
        StartCoroutine(FadeOut(mySprite, 3));
    }

    public IEnumerator FadeOut(SpriteRenderer spriteToFade, float duration)
    {
        //DoFadeOutStuff
    }
}
```

Here I've tried to set the object active in the Awake function of its own code but I've also tried it in the both functions of Class1 and its Start function. I've also tried to handle it for the whole array in an foreach loop. Always the same result. All I want to do is to set it active, right now I don't even care if my fade out stuff works correctly. First I thought it was because my instantiated object is a clone but I can't find anything about it, so even if the solution is pretty obvious, please help!

Comment: If a gameObject is inactive so are it's components(AKA it's scripts) You will need another object to activate this one.

Comment: I've also tried to set it in Class1, which lies on the button that is a different object, if that is what you mean

Comment: Except class one can't be attached to a GameObject since it isn't a MonoBehaviour.

Comment: well, I'm sorry, I just missed it, I just retyped it rather than to copy it, will change it

Comment: @Eddge I hope the code is correct now, I'm sorry, I recreated the code to leave out all irrelevant stuff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're referencing the actual prefab itself, which isn't actually active in the scene. You need to create a gameobject and set its value to the instantiated prefab. The following should work

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Class1 : MonoBehaviour
{
[SerializeField]
private GameObject[] myPrefabs;

public void ButtonEffect()
{
    var go = InstantiatedPrefab();
    go.GetComponent<MyClass>().OnButtonEffect();
}

private GameObject InstantiatedPrefab()
{
    var index = Random.Range(0, myPrefabs.Length);
    return Instantiate(myPrefabs[index]);
}
}

using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;

public class MyClass : MonoBehaviour
{
private SpriteRenderer mySprite;

private void Start()
{
    mySprite = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
}

public void OnButtonEffect()
{
    StartCoroutine(FadeOut(mySprite, 3));
}

private IEnumerator FadeOut(SpriteRenderer spriteToFade, float duration)
{
    print("FadeOut");
    yield return 0;

}
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot, this totally solves the problem! I was already thinking this must have been the problem but didn't know how to solve it, so yes, thank you very much!